# Scala implicit object vs implicit val

Tags: scala, implicit

I've seen two ways (one less than the other) of declaring `implicit` for **typeclass pattern** in Scala.

```
implicit val instance1 = new Typeclass { def do = ??? }
implicit object instance2 extends Typeclass { def do = ??? }
```

How are they different? Should one prefer one to the other for certain times? I find `implicit val` much more commonly used than `implicit object` and I've yet to find many resources about `implicit object`.

Answer (score 16):

One difference is that the `object` version is going to be lazily initialized, i.e. it's constructor will not be called until the first time it is used. For example:

```
trait Incrementer[T] {
  def inc(x: T)
}

def increment[T](x: T)(implicit ev: Incrementer[T]) = ev.inc(x)

implicit object IntIncrementer extends Incrementer[Int] {
  println("IntIncrementer is being constructed...")

  def inc(x: Int) = x + 1
}

implicit val DoubleIncrementer extends Incrementer[Double] {
  println("DoubleIncrementer is being constructed...")

  def inc(x: Double) = x + 1D
}
```

Note that you will not see the message from `IntIncrementer` until it is used, e.g.

```
increment(1)  //this prints "IntIncrementer is being constructed..."
```

The message from `DoubleIncrementer`, however, will be displayed when it is defined. So the initialization of `implicit object` is lazy while the initialization of `implicit val` is strict.

Comment: So, the decision to use an `implicit`  `object` versus `val` depends on whether to prefer lazy or strict initialization?

Comment: That might be one consideration (though you could always use `lazy val` to get laziness with a `val`), but not the only one. For example, a `val` member can be overridden in a subclass while an `object` member cannot. I'm sure there are plenty of other differences.